# jQuery $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem including a jQuery script in my webpage. I always get the error "$ is not a function" in line 6. I reduced my script to the following very simple one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  myTest();
});

function myTest(){
  window.console && console.log($("#test"));
}
```

Why is there an error in line 6? Why not already in line 1?

Comment: hey, could it be that you are using wordpress? If so it is another error, than a missing include.

Comment: Did you include the Jquery library?

Comment: It's Microsoft SharePoint and jQuery is included. Does $(document).ready(function() ... work without jQuery?

Comment: @jlai79 no it won't. I can guarantee you that jQuery is not being loaded correctly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Then why do I get no error on line **$(document).ready(function(){** but on the line with **$("#test")**?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, line numbers given in javascript error messages are ***never*** reliable. Ignore the line and focus on the error message itself.

Comment: No idea what was wrong. Now it works.

Comment: The answers provided are correct.  Whenever you get an error type $(...) is not a function, know that the problem comes from a missing JQuery library. Also note that the order is important too.

Answer (score 9):

You have not included `jquery.js` in your page, or the path you have used is incorrect. Here is an example one using Google's CDN:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // your code here...
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The line numbers given in browser error messages are notoriously unreliable, always use the actual error message as a guide to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please download and include jquery.js or jquery.min.js

in script tag

Give jquery.js path in script src attribute

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that jQuery is not included